# Software store only contain the installed apps and unable to install .deb files

Tags: 14.04, steam, ubuntu-store

I'm trying to install Steam and i downloaded the .deb file from the page but when i click install on it it just flashed "installing" for about 0.3
 seconds.

As shown in the screen shot

[image: As shown in the screen shot]

**HELP**

EDIT:I ran this:`sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/steam_latest.deb`

And this error was shown.

`

```
Selecting previously unselected package steam-launcher.
(Reading database ... 154515 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../Downloads/steam_latest.deb ...
Unpacking steam-launcher (1.0.0.52) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam-launcher:
 steam-launcher depends on curl; however:
  Package curl is not installed.
 steam-launcher depends on python-apt; however:
  Package python-apt is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package steam-launcher (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam-launcher
```

`

Comment: Uh i am new to Linux so if the needed infos are not provided please inform me.

Comment: are you sure about *0.3 Seconds ??* ;-P

Comment: try `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/your/debfile/your-steam-deb.deb` in terminal

Comment: `dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege`

Comment: Ah.. I see some missing dependencies.. now try `sudo  apt-get install --fix-broken`